# How to calculate $\mathrm{TP}(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, hochschild-homology

$\DeclareMathOperator\TP{TP}$I am trying to learn about topological periodic cyclic homology following the notes:

https://www.uni-muenster.de/IVV5WS/WebHop/user/nikolaus/Papers/Lectures.pdf

https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2019/2019MorrowNotes.pdf

I've seen the calculation of $\TP(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and I was wondering how to calculate $\TP(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$ as complexes? Most of the theorems I can see for general smooth commutative rings $R$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ seem to relate a certain associated graded of a filtration (that I don't understand yet) with a complex computing crystalline cohomology.

But I would hope that in this simple case, there would be a more "canonical" relationship between de Rham complexes (of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[t]$) and $\TP(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$   (meaning without filtrations)? If it simplifies things, I would also be fine with inverting p, namely a canonical de Rham description of $\TP(\mathbb{F}_p[t])[1/p]$ as chain complexes. (I understand that the actual homotopy groups may be pretty trivial after inverting $p$, but hopefully the spirit of the question is clear.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first reduction is probably due to Akhil Mathew, cf. [[Bhatt–Morrow–Scholze: Topological Hochschild homology and integral $p$-adic Hodge theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03261), Proof of Thm 8.17]. We have an equivalence

\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator\THH{THH}
\DeclareMathOperator\HH{HH}
\THH(\mathbb F_p[t])&=\THH(\mathbb F_p)\otimes_{\mathbb S}\THH(\mathbb S[t])\\
&=\THH(\mathbb F_p)\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb S}\THH(\mathbb S[t])\\
&=\THH(\mathbb F_p)\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\HH(\mathbb Z[t]/\mathbb Z)\\
\end{align*}

in $\DeclareMathOperator\Fun{Fun}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\Fun(B\mathbb T,D(\mathbb Z))$.

Now for every $M\in\Fun(B\mathbb T,D(\mathbb Z))$, the map $M\to M\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\THH(\mathbb F_p)$ induces a $p$-adic equivalence after applying $(-)^{t\mathbb T}$ (in *loc. cit.*, they show this under connectivity of $M$, but it is not necessary). It follows from the following observations:

1. $\DeclareMathOperator\fib{fib}\fib(\mathbb Z_p\to\THH(\mathbb F_p))\simeq(\mathbb Z_p)_{hC_p}$ in $\Fun(B\mathbb T,D(\mathbb Z))$ (one way to see this is that $\DeclareMathOperator\TR{TR}\mathbb Z_p=\TR(\mathbb F_p)$, and use the fiber sequence $\TR(X)_{hC_p}\to \TR(X)\to X$ for every bounded below cyclotomic spectrum $X$).
2. The $\mathbb T$-action on $(\mathbb F_p)_{hC_p}$ is induced.

In short, we have $\DeclareMathOperator\TP{TP}\DeclareMathOperator\HP{HP}\TP(\mathbb F_p[t])=\HP(\mathbb Z[t]/\mathbb Z)_p^\wedge$ in $D(\mathbb Z)$.

Now an unpublished result by Arpon Raksit says that $\DeclareMathOperator\dR{dR}\HP(\mathbb Z[t]/\mathbb Z)\simeq\widehat\dR_{\mathbb Z[t]/\mathbb Z}\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z^{t\mathbb T}$ as $\mathbb E_\infty$-$\mathbb Z$-algebras. As far as I understand, his argument does not extend to polynomial rings on two variables.

Comment: I have a question. Why wouldn't a similar argument work for a general smooth algebra R? There is an HKR theorem by Hesselholt mentioned in Morrow's notes $$THH(F_p)\otimes_F_p \Omega^*_{R/F_p} \cong THH(R).$$ Is it because the result of B-M-S you cite only works over Z not F_p?

Comment: Or maybe I should say it is a general trick which works for algebras which lift to the sphere spectrum?

Comment: @onefishtwofish This argument works for (associative) $\mathbb F_p$-algebras with a spherical lift, yes. The statement $\TP(R\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb F_p)=\HP(R/\mathbb Z)_p^\wedge$ holds in $\operatorname{Sp}$ for associative $\mathbb Z$-algebras $R$ as well for $p>2$, cf. [Petrov–Vologodsky, On the periodic topological ...](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03246), but the isomorphism is not known to be $\mathbb Z$-linear.

Comment: In your comment about Petrov-Vologodsky, should $\mathbb{Z}$ be $\mathbb{Z}_p$? I have no understanding what it means for an isomorphism of abelian groups not to be $\mathbb{Z}$-linear...

Comment: @onefishtwofish Every equivalence is established up to $p$-completion, thus I would drop the subscript for sake of simplicity. It is not an isomorphism of abelian groups, but the following: you have two objects $X,Y\in D(\mathbb Z)$, and an isomorphism $X\to Y$ *after* passing along the forgetful functor $D(\mathbb Z)\to\operatorname{Sp}$. A priori, it does not lift to a map in $D(\mathbb Z)$ (but such a lift, if exists, is automatically an isomorphism).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!